# Does taking advantage of dynamic columns in Cassandra require duplicated data in each row?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

I've been trying to understand how one would model time series data in Cassandra, like shown in the below image from a popular System Design Interview video, where counts of views are stored hourly. [image]

While I would think the schema for this time series data would be something like the below, I don't believe this would lead to data actually being stored in the way the screenshot shows.

```
CREATE table views_data {
    video_id uuid
    channel_name varchar
    video_name varchar
    viewed_at timestamp
    count int
    PRIMARY_KEY (video_id, viewed_at)
};
```

Instead, I'm assuming it would lead to something like this (inspired by [datastax](https://www.datastax.com/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows)), where technically there is a single row for each `video_id`, but the other columns seem like they would all be duplicated, such as `channel_name`, `video_name`, etc.. within the row for each unique `viewed_at`.

```
[cassandra-cli]

list views_data;
RowKey: A
=> (channel_name='System Design Interview', video_name='Distributed Cache', count=2, viewed_at=1370463146717000)
=> (channel_name='System Design Interview', video_name='Distributed Cache', count=3, viewed_at=1370463282090000)
=> (channel_name='System Design Interview', video_name='Distributed Cache', count=8, viewed_at=1370463282093000)
-------------------
RowKey: B 
=> (channel_name='Some other channel', video_name='Some video', count=4, viewed_at=1370463282093000)
```

I assume this is still considered dynamic wide row, as we're able to expand the row for each unique `(video_id, viewed_at)` combination. But it seems less than ideal that we need to duplicate the extra information such as `channel_name` and `video_name`.

**Is the screenshot of modeling time series data misleading or is it actually possible to have dynamic columns where certain columns in the row do not need to be duplicated?
If I was upserting time series data to this row, I wouldn't want to have to provide the `channel_name` and `video_name` for every single upsert, I would just want to provide the `count`.**

Comment: Thank you Erick, much appreciated!! Looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to duplicate the values of columns within the rows of a partition. It is possible to model your table to accomodate your use case.

In Cassandra, there is a concept of "static columns" -- columns which have the same value for all rows within a partition.

Here's the schema of an example table that contains two static columns, `colour` and `item`:

```
CREATE TABLE statictbl (
    pk int,
    ck text,
    c int,
    colour text static,
    item text static,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, ck)
)
```

In this table, each partition share the same `colour` and `item` for all rows of the same partition. For example, partition `pk=1` has the same `colour='red'` and `item='apple'` for all rows:

```
 pk | ck | colour | item   | c
----+----+--------+--------+----
  1 |  a |    red |  apple | 12
  1 |  b |    red |  apple | 23
  1 |  c |    red |  apple | 34
```

If I insert a new partition `pk=2`:

```
INSERT INTO statictbl (pk, ck, colour, item, c) VALUES (2, 'd', 'yellow', 'banana', 45)
```

we get:

```
 pk | ck | colour | item   | c
----+----+--------+--------+----
  2 |  d | yellow | banana | 45
```

If I then insert another row withOUT specifying a `colour` and `item`:

```
INSERT INTO statictbl (pk, ck, c) VALUES (2, 'e', 56)
```

the new row with `ck='e'` still has the `colour` and `item` populated even though I didn't insert a value for them:

```
 pk | ck | colour | item   | c
----+----+--------+--------+----
  2 |  d | yellow | banana | 45
  2 |  e | yellow | banana | 56
```

In your case, both the channel and video names will share the same value for all rows in a given partition if you declare them as `static` and you only ever need to insert them once. Note that when you update the value of static columns, ALL the rows for that partition will reflect the updated value.

For details, see [Sharing a static column in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/refStaticCol.html). Cheers!